# Vertical carousel with automatic transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want a carousel with vertical thumbnails as shown in the link below:

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/11/

But in this example, images are changed only on hover over, I want to have an automatic slider as well. Say image changes every **10 seconds**.

Also, this doesn't work in Firefox. Though my primary requirement is to have an automatic slider along with manual image change(hover or click).

If anyone has come across, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `auto` configuration option for the carousel.

```
    $(function() {
        $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
            items: 1,
            auto: 5000, // Slide automatically after 5 seconds
            scroll: {
                fx: 'none'
            },
            pagination: {
                container: '#pager',
                event: 'mouseenter',
                anchorBuilder: function(nr, item) {
                    var src = item.attr('src').replace('/large/', '/small/');
                    return '<img src="'+ src +'" border="0" />';
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Pulkit, this helps. I was trying to write 'True' as value of auto instead of 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Here's are two carousels that I've used before: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm  http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

They both allow to be vertical, and to automatically slide at an interval.

**Edit**

Just had a quick look at the plugin you posted about, and it does seem to support sliding at intervals: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/10/